# How do I add directories to PATH?

Tags: bash, path, rbenv, webfaction

Long story made short, I am trying to issue myself an SSL certificate using LetsEncrypt, and have recently installed rbenv to make this process easier. After installing rbenv, I check to see if everything checks out using

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

I than get this message saying that there are no versions of ruby installed. After trying to install ruby using the command

`"rbenv install 2.3.1"`

I get this error

```
rbenv: no such command `install'
```

Is it because the path to my rbenv shims aren't in my PATH variable ? If this is the case how do I add directories to my PATH variable ? I know you have to add them to your bash_profile file, but am not sure where in this file I need to add something, and what I need to add.

~/.bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

function letsencrypt_webfaction {
    PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin GEM_HOME=$HOME/.letsencrypt_webfaction/gems RUBYLIB=$GEM_HOME/lib ruby2.2 $HOME/.letsencrypt_webfaction/gems/bin/letsencrypt_webfaction $*
}

eval "$(rbenv init -)"


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always be careful when editing the profile.

Better make a backup first

- switch to home directory:
  `cd`
- list hiden files:
  `ls -la .bash*`
- make a backup copy of .bash_profile:
  `cp -p .bash_profile .bash_profile.bak`
- check the current PATH: `echo $PATH`
- check if ruby is in the PATH: `which ruby`
- check the ruby version: `ruby --version`

I am not sure where this function is comming from in your .bash_profile: `function letsencrypt_webfaction()`

Use `:` as a separator and add a new directory `new_dir` to your PATH, use `$PATH` to keep the contents of the actual PATH, then export the new PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/new_dir:/new_lib
export PATH
```

Verify if the PATH is what you need from the terminal: `echo $PATH`

Personaly I sugest making a backup of .bash_profile as it is. Comment out with `#` the 3 lines for the function and the others where the PATH appears and add this:

```
export RUBYLIB=$HOME/lib
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/gems
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH:
```

After this please check the bulet points above and see if you have the ruby version you expect.

Comment: Also the [ruby at webfaction link](https://blog.webfaction.com/2012/11/a-look-at-our-ruby-setup/).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions) you should install the [`ruby-build`](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme) plugin:

> The `rbenv install` command doesn't ship with `rbenv` out of the box,
>   but is provided by the [`ruby-build`](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme) project.