# Python subprocess error: Popen, call, run "No such file or directory: error

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having issues with the subprocess module. I'm trying to run a terminal command in Python, which works perfectly fine in the terminal. The command is:

```
hrun SomeAction LogFile
```

I've tried a variety of options, including call(), run(), check_output(), and Popen(). No matter which method I use, I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hrun': 'hrun'
```

My code is:

```
    output = Popen(["hrun", "SomeAction", log_file_name], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

where "hrun" and "SomeAction" are strings and log_file_name is a string variable.
I found other SO issues and, most (if not all) were resolved with either shell=True (which I dont want), or because the issue was due to a string instead of a list argument.

Thanks!

Comment: That means the `hrun` command is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to run a command from a prompt within a script why not use something like

```
import os
os.system("your command")
```

You should be able to just run it like

```
os.system("hrun SomeAction LogFile")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried os.system(), and it still doesn't work, but at least it doesn't throw an error! I'm getting this output: sh: hrun: command not found. I'm also getting an unexpected output, which I'm assuming has to do with the command not found issue.

Comment: I don't recognize `hrun` as a standard command, so maybe if it's a custom script and is missing from your `PATH` variable in your environment? Does the command work in a normal terminal?

Comment: hrun I believe is a Perl script. I'm running it on Linux, and yes it works as a normal terminal command

Comment: @helloworld95 I would try finding the Perl script on your machine and adding it to your PATH. You can do this through the `sys` module within your script. Alternatively you can `os.chdir()` to that location within your script and it should work (personally what I recommend cause changing PATH can have unexpected consequenses), or you can add it to your PATH following a process like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188012/how-do-i-add-directories-to-path